# connect SQL server file (mdf) with R tool

Tags: sql-server, r, visual-studio-2017

It's possible to connect SQL server file (mdf) with R tool in visual studio 2017? I tried that many times but the connection failed.

From visual studio2017, I want to connect R with Sql server database.
I created R project then from R (`tools--> Data --> Add database connection --> Attach database file`) but connection failed.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on exactly what you're trying to do? MDF files are only usable with SQL Server. Are you trying to find an R command that attaches a database to SQL Server, or what specific steps are you trying?

Comment: from visual studio2017,I want to connect R with Sql server database .I created R project then from (R tools--> Data --> Add database connection --> Attach database file ) but connection failed

Comment: Not familiar with that menu personally, but I suspect you want to create a native SQL connection, or an ODBC/OLE connection to the SQL Server. File connection doesn't work with SQL Server `.mdf` files, as @BrentOzar noted.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming you are trying to use SQL Expess localDB. Since you did not give specific error messages my answer is also very generic.

Here is a good reading about LocadDB.  [Introducing LocalDB, an improved SQL Express.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlexpress/2011/07/12/introducing-localdb-an-improved-sql-express/)

Check if you have LocalDB installed and what version by running this in a command window.

```
sqllocaldb.exe info MSSQLLocalDB
```

[From books oniline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-2016-express-localdb):

> Once installed, LocalDB is an instance of SQL Server Express that can
>   create and open SQL Server databases. The system database files for
>   the database are stored in the users' local AppData path which is
>   normally hidden. For example
>   C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Local
>   DB\Instances\LocalDBApp1. User database files are stored where the
>   user designates, typically somewhere in the C:\Users\\Documents\
>   folder.

If it not installed you can install 2016 using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42774739/how-to-install-localdb-2016-along-with-visual-studio-2017) method.

Once you are confirmed that you have localDB installed and version is correct use this document [Working with SQL Server LocalDB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/working-with-sql?tabs=aspnetcore2x) to create new database(files) or attach existing files. See section [SQL Server Express LocalDB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/working-with-sql?tabs=aspnetcore2x#sql-server-express-localdb).